# 10 most frequent value in sql column - linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a table named `details` with these columns:

```
product id = int
product price = float
products' category = nvarchar(50)
```

This table has no primary key (or foreign key, if that's matter).

I want to perform a query which returns a list of strings which contains the 10 most frequent product's category (the categories with the most products belong to), in descending order.

How can I perform this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var tenMostFrequentCategories = products.GroupBy(product=>product.Category)
                                        .OrderByDescending(grp=>grp.Count())
                                        .Select(grp=>grp.Key)
                                        .ToList();
```

where I assume that `products` is your data context class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `var tenMostFrequentCategories = products.GroupBy(product >= product.Category)
        .OrderByDescending(grp >= grp.Count())
        .SelectMany(grp >= grp.Key).Take(10)
                                        .ToList();`?

Comment: @Christos -is this query works if i replace "products" with "db.getTable<details>()" ?    sorry for my ignorance, i'm new to linq-to-sql

Comment: @rzarviv Of course it will work. No problem at all dude.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the SQL -

```
Select top 10 [Category], count(distinct productID) as NumProducts
from details
group by [category]
order by count(distinct productID) desc
```

The `group by` will count products by their category, then the `top 10` returns only the ten most.  If there are ties for 10th place, it will only pick one - if you need it to return both, let me know.

Comment: I forgot to mention : i work with linq-to-sql  :(

Comment: Ok, sorry!  Was confused by your sql-server tag.